# Why/how long do migrated questions still show up in the search results page?

Tags: discussion, support, search, migrated-questions

Why after nearly 2 weeks migrated questions still show up in the search results page? Does anyone care about those migrated ones?

[image]

I can avoid displaying the migrated as well as display only the migrated by modifying my [search query](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) but don't you think by default no-one really cares about migrated questions and they should be hidden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Migrated questions are auto-deleted from the site they've left after 30 days, so they'll certainly drop out of your search results at that time.

One supposes that they're not deleted right away in order to give some time to manage incorrect migrations.

See also: [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)